# Google cloud function is not able to access data from GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have one cloud function which is triggering the dataflow. For this process it should get dataflow template which kept in a gcs bucket.

Using a default service account (linked to cloud function) with Editor Role I am able to fetch this file.
But using a custom service account with below roles it showing 403 status.

```
Cloud Build Service Account
Cloud Build Service Agent
Cloud Functions Service Agent
Container Registry Service Agent
Dataflow Developer
Storage Object Admin
```

The error I am getting is

```
2020-10-21 11:14:20.820 WARN 1 --- [p2094777811-167] .a.b.s.e.g.u.RetryHttpRequestInitializer : Request failed with code 403, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying): https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/<project id>/locations/australia-southeast1/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://<path>/templates/i-template.
```

Do I missed any roles? Please help

Comment: Try to add Storage Admin role. If it works, I will answer with more explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that you do not have the required permissions to execute the operation:

> RetryHttpRequestInitializer : Request failed with code 403, performed 0 retries due to IOExceptions, performed 0 retries due to unsuccessful status codes, HTTP framework says request can be retried, (caller responsible for retrying): https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects//locations/australia-southeast1/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs:///templates/i-template.

You mentioned that by using the `Editor` role, you were able to execute the operation without issues. This is because, as an *Editor*, you are able to accomplish many tasks on a vast majority of resources: viewer permissions, plus permissions for actions that modify state, such as changing existing resources.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic-definitions) for more information about *Basic role definitions*.

Now, you can narrow down the permission scope to a minimum set of permissions which will allow you to have more control over each resource. For this, I would recommend that you add the `Cloud Functions Developer` and `Dataflow Admin` roles.

Being a CF developer, you will have full access to functions, operations and locations. Then, the *Dataflow Admin* role encompasses all the necessary permissions for creating and managing dataflow jobs and also includes some Cloud Storage permissions, such as *storage.buckets.get* and *create, get, and list* objects.

Lastly, please make sure that you have the necessary permissions for the trigger sources, i.e. Cloud Storage, and using `Storage Admin` should be enough.

Please note that you can always double check your roles along with its permissions by looking at the [predefined roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles) tables for each Google Cloud resource, in case you need to narrow it down further.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give Storage read access (asuming that you are not using [fine grained permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control)) to this service account you are missing at least the `Storage Object Viewer role` for this account.

Comment: I am using Storage Object Admin , I have edited the question also.

Comment: for this API https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3 do we need any other roles?

Comment: Did you added Dataflow Service Agent role?

Comment: Dataflow Service Agent role is not added. Are u mentioning about roles/dataflow.worker?